# In Windows 10, allow notifications to appear in the notifications bar, but disable them from popping up

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I would like to keep the notifications in the tray,
[image], but I don't like them popping up on the screen. Is there a way to stop them from popping up while keeping their existence in the tray? I know I found a way to disable the sounds, but I don't see a way to disable the popping up (without disabling them completely).

Comment: I am not sure you can do this. In part it depends on how the software vendor implemented the notification. Apple puts up a notification when I connect my phone. If I do nothing, the notification vanishes on its own. I look at the notification and then delete it. No need (for me) to retain them.

Comment: I just have some news sites sending me notifications on chrome and it gets annoying to have them popup while I'm working on something. I do like to click the tray and see what's going on. I get the feeling it's impossible but I wanted to ask and see.

Comment: Use the Focus Assist settings (Windows 10 Settings) to set priorities so that only important notifications pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications can be customized for each "sender" program:

Go to 'Settings' > 'System' > 'Notifications & Actions'; then, click on an offending "sender" program whose notifications you would like to modify:

[image]

To remove the popup banner for this "sender", de-select 'Show notification banners'.
Confirm 'Show notifications in action center' is selected to keep the notifications in your tray.

[image]

Return to 'Notifications & Actions' and repeat as necessary for other banners.